# How to put divs on sides of the screen over the rest of page content?

Tags: css, layout, sidebar

So I am trying to create a browser game and I want to add 24 buttons, 12 on each side of the screen. No matter what I do (for example changing the position property of both the parent and the child divs to every possible option), the rest of the web content moves below the buttons.

```
<div id="buttonsContainer">
    <div class="button">There are 24</div>
    <div class="button">buttons in total</div>
    <div class="button">But I included</div>
    <div class="button">Only 5</div>
    <div class="button">For demostration</div>
</div>
```

I included a badly drawn plan of what I want to achieve. The site content and the buttons are on separate divs of the same 'level'.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: purple;
}

main {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.block-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
}

.block-list li {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white;
  margin: .5rem;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.side-buttons {
  position: absolute;
}

.side-buttons li {
  list-style: none;
  color: purple;
  background: yellow;
  margin: .25rem;
}

#right {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#left {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <ul class="block-list">
      <li>block</li>
      <li>block</li>
      <li>block</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="block-list">
      <li>block</li>
      <li>block</li>
      <li>block</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="block-list">
      <li>block</li>
      <li>block</li>
      <li>block</li>
    </ul>
  </main>
  <ul class="side-buttons" id="left">
    <li>side button left</li>
    <li>side button left</li>
    <li>side button left</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="side-buttons" id="right">
    <li>side button right</li>
    <li>side button right</li>
    <li>side button right</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply `position: fixed` to your container. The idea is to position your container as fixed element, but it will consume our click events, so add `pointer-events: none;` to it and then restore them on buttons.

```css
#buttonsContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#buttonsContainer button {
  pointer-event: auto;
}
```